# How to resolve "Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not found" error while installing Zoom on Linux Fedora 29?

Tags: fedora, qt

I am trying to install a program (zoom) on a Linux Fedora 29 64bit installation.  I think I have all prerequisites installed, but one problem remains

```
[root@myhost~]# ldd /opt/zoom/zoom | more
/opt/zoom/zoom: /lib64/libQt5Quick.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /opt/zoom/zoom)
```

The related package qt5-qtdeclarative-5.11.3-1.fc29.x86_64 is already installed.  How do I resolve this?

---

Update for requested info:

```
[root@myhost~]# updatedb && locate libQt5Quick.so.5
/opt/zoom/libQt5Quick.so.5
/opt/zoom/libQt5Quick.so.5.9
/opt/zoom/libQt5Quick.so.5.9.6
/usr/lib64/libQt5Quick.so.5
/usr/lib64/libQt5Quick.so.5.11
/usr/lib64/libQt5Quick.so.5.11.3
[root@myhost~]# strings -d /usr/lib64/libQt5Quick.so.5 | grep Qt.*API
Qt_5.11.3_PRIVATE_API
```

Comment: Add the output of `updatedb && locate libQt5Quick.so.5` and `strings -d /path/to/libQt5Quick.so.5 | grep Qt.*API` to your question.

Comment: I've updated the question.  I notice the string doesn't match...but don't know what to make of that

Comment: There is no object `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API` in version 5.11.3, but usually is in version 5.9.6 . .... Solution : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zoom:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && /opt/zoom/zoom`

Comment: That  solved it!  I'll leave question up to help others - if you post as an answer I can also accept solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Fedora` I had the same issue when installing the `Private Internet Access` [client UI](https://privateinternetaccess.com). I resolved it by updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running the client, like so:

```
user$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/piavpn/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} && nohup /opt/piavpn/bin/pia-client &
```

But actually, this work-around isn't exclusive to `Fedora` or to `Private Internet Access`. In general, you can try it when you encounter the **OP**s issue in other circumstances.

In summary, here's the wrapper script that I use (simple), along with a few comments for myself:

```
# ===============================================================
# NOTE: The PIA VPN GUI client will download an update to:
#       /opt/piavpn/var/update/pia-linux-w.x.z-NNNN.run
# ===============================================================
# To install an update, you must run the above bash(1) script
# as yourself (e.g. "jdoe"), NOT as user "root":
# ===============================================================
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/piavpn/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} && \
       nohup /opt/piavpn/bin/pia-client > /dev/null &
# ===============================================================
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue when attempting to run TortoiseHg, specifically version 6.5.1 on Rocky 8. Had performed the following steps prior to the issue:

- Extracted the tortoisehg-6.5.1 tar ball.
- Installed necessary python 3.9 packages by running `sudo yum install python39` and `sudo yum install python39-devel` .
- Updated alternatives to the newer python with commands `sudo alternatives  --config python3` and `sudo alternatives --config python` and selecting python3.9 in both cases.
- Updated pip3 by running command `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`.
- Installed various python dependencies with `sudo pip3 install` and individually installed `mercurial`, `PyQt5`, `QScintilla`, and `iniparse`.

The issue arose because installing PyQt5 without specifying a version installed version **5.15.10** that was not compatible with tortoisehg6.5.1, whereas version **5.15.9** was compatible. Running `sudo pip3 uninstall PyQt5` followed by `sudo pip3 install PyQt5==5.15.9` allowed the command `thg` to properly open the tortoisehg GUI.